# how to make the below output of the command pass not fail

Tags: regex, bash, awk, grep

how to make the below output of the regex command pass not fail

```
grep -E '^[[:space:]]*-a[[:space:]]+always,exit[[:space:]]+-F[[:space:]]+arch=b32[[:space:]]+-S[[:space:]]+creat[[:space:]]+-S[[:space:]]+open[[:space:]]+-S[[:space:]]+openat[[:space:]]+-S[[:space:]]+truncate[[:space:]]+-S[[:space:]]+ftruncate[[:space:]]+-F[[:space:]]+exit=-EACCES[[:space:]]+-F[[:space:]]+auid>=500[[:space:]]+-F[[:space:]]+auid!=4294967295[[:space:]]+-k[[:space:]]+access[[:space:]]*$' /etc/audit/rules.d/*.rules | /usr/bin/awk '{print} END {if (NR != 0) print "pass" ; else print "fail"}'
```

I tried the below and still fail

```
echo -e "-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S creat -S open -S openat -S truncate -S ftruncate -F exit=-EACCES -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=4294967295 -k access\n-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S creat -S open -S openat -S truncate -S ftruncate -F exit=-EACCES -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=4294967295 -k access\n-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S creat -S open -S openat -S truncate -S ftruncate -F exit=-EPERM -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=4294967295 -k access\n-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S creat -S open -S openat -S truncate -S ftruncate -F exit=-EPERM -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=4294967295 -k access" > /etc/audit/rules.d/access.rules
```

Comment: `| /usr/bin/awk '{print} END {if (NR != 0) print "pass" ; else print "fail"}'` that's a strange way of doing that. Just `if grep ...; then echo pass; else echo fail; fi`. So where in your grep do you match the newline? `cess\n-a` <- this newline. I do not understand, what do you want to "make"? You want to change the `grep` regex so that `awk` will print `pass` or do you want to change `echo` line? Or both?

Comment: I know i need the above grep to work as it is done by a program and i need that program to pass the check by following this command and make it pass

Comment: i need that grep command to pass so invented the echo command but still not pass it faild

Comment: Your pattern is looking for "`auid>=500"`, but the file has "`auid>=1000`" on each line.